# Class and Abstract Class in Java

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

I am a Java beginner and I learn by reading articles, books and watching YouTube videos. Recently I came across the terms **class** and **abstract class** and I really have no idea if they are the same thing or not. It seems that no one has really made a comparison of them.

My question is: Are they the same? If not, what are the differences?
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to read Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel. You can get it from web, it is free as I remember.

Comment: Ask google. You will have plenty of answers. StackOverflow is about specific coding questions, not general ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `class` and a `abstract class` are different in subtle ways.

A `class` can be instanciated and used as an object whereas a `abstract class` cannot be instanciated.

You use a `abstract class` to abstract some behaviour of common classes.

Also only a `abstract class` can have abstract methods that are only defined but not implemented. The implementation is done in sub classes of the `abstract class`.

There are many more things but this is to much for a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use `abstract` class in this situation is to force everyone inheriting your base class to override the abstract `doInit` method. Without the class and the method being abstract, they may forget to do so, and the compiler would not catch them.

In addition to this pragmatic purpose, abstract classes provide a powerful way to communicate your design idea to the readers of your code. An abstract class tells the reader that the methods inside provide some common implementation for a group of related classes, rather than implementing a single concept that you are modeling. Very often communicating your intent to your readers is as important as it is to write correct code, because otherwise they might break something while maintaining your code.

It is customary in Java to call abstract classes Abstract...; in your example that would be AbstractParent.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void init() {
       doInit();
    }
    public abstract void doInit();
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public void doInit() {
       // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class can have abstract methods but normal class cant have abstract methods.
We cannot create an object for the abstract classes. When we inherit the abstract class we should implement the abstract method which we inherit.

Answer (score 0):

A class is can be used to create an object. An abstract class cannot be used to create an object.
You must extend an abstract class to use attributes or methods of it

Answer (score 0):

**Abstract classes** can not be instantiated directly and must be subclassed in order to be used. Please read the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is a class that includes abstract methods. Abstract methods are methods that are declared without an implementation. A good place to look is 
 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)